# How can I generate both an aar and apk of my Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I am developing an Android library in Android Studio.

I have also created a dummy android application project to import that library and test it. For that reason I have imported my android library as a *Library* into this android application. My problem is that when I generate the apk in the output folder I can only see the apk and there is no folder for the generated aar.

How can I generate my aar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured this out, it wasn't difficult but I'll just post the answer here just in case I save someone of time. When I selected build apk the aar isn't built in the outputs of the main project, however it's built in the outputs of the respective library.

Comment: The APK and AAR are only created, if you select "Build -> Rebuild Project" in Android Studio. Selecting "Build -> Make Project" only creates the APK but not the AAR file. Another option is to build the project from the command line using "./gradlew assemble"